# "wrong first argument type. Found: 'android.widget.Compoundbutton.oncheckedchangelistener', required: 'android.content.context'"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-spinner, android-switch

this code:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Hours_array, R.layout.MainActivity);       
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.MainActivity);  
Hrs.setAdapter(adapter);
```

the "this" in the first line of code throws this error:

```
wrong first argument type. Found: 'android.widget.Compoundbutton.oncheckedchangelistener', required: 'android.content.context
```

I am trying to use a switch to change a spinner's entry that includes hours, from regular time, to military time.

If you can help please do.  thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you refer `this` inside `oncheckedchangelistener`, it will refer to `oncheckedchangelistener` object and not `MainActivity`.

**Instead of**

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Hours_array, R.layout.MainActivity);
```

**Use**

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(MainActivity.this, R.array.Hours_array, R.layout.MainActivity);
```